# Rails: With models A has_many B belongs_to C return A where B belongs to C and B is most recently created for given A?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I have three models A, B, and C, where `A has_many B`; `B belongs to C`, and `B has a created_on timestamp`. C has_many A through B.

I want to return *all* A where A has a B that belongs to C and where B is the most recently created B for that A.

I can do this with a method loop.  Can this be done solely with named_scopes?, or is some other elegant/efficient manner?

As per request for real world (TM) examples A, B and C can be imagined as, for instance, Pets (A), PetsName (B), and Names (C). PetsNames are given to Pets at a specific time, and any given Name can be given to many Pets.  Any Pet can have many Names (a :through relationship).  For a given Name I want *all* of the Pets in which that Name is the most recently created PetName for that Pet.  The call may look something like `@name.pets.most_recently_named_as`

Comment: Hard to understand with using A,B,C.  Try editing to use real nouns (i.e. Recipe, Ingredient, etc ...)  I think you will be a better response.

Comment: I've provided a real world example as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rails way to do this is a named scope on pets.

Something like this:

```
class Pets
  has_many :pet_names
  has_many :names, :through => :pet_names

  named_scope :with_current_name, lambda {|name| 
    { :joins => "JOIN (pet_names pna, names) " +
        "ON (pna.pet_id = pets.id AND pna.name_id = names.id) " +
        "LEFT JOIN pet_names pnb " +
        "ON (pnb.pet_id = pets.id AND pna.created_at < pnb.created_at)", 
      :conditions => ["pnb.id IS NULL AND names.id = ? ", name]
    }
  }
end

Pets.with_current_name(@name)
@name.pets.with_current_name(@name)
```

To keep things name centric you could always define a method on C/Name that invokes the named scope.

You could always do

```
class Name < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pet_names
  has_many :pets, :through => :pet_names

  def currently_named_pets
    Pets.with_current_name(self)
  end
end
```

And

```
@name.currently_named_pets
```

It's a pretty complicated join. Which is an indicator that you should probably should rethink the way you store this information. Why is it so important that Names be in a separate table?

You might be better off doing something like this:

After adding `name` and `old_name` columns to Pet:

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :old_name, Array
  def after_initialization 
    @old_name ||= []
  end

  def name= new_name
    self.old_name << new_name
    self.name = new_name
  end

  named_scope :with_name, lambda {|name|
     { :conditions => {:name => name}}
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks much EmFi, I'll try that named scope out. I know it's a complicated join, that's why I asked.  The greatly simplified example here is just a proxy for my real models which nicely stand alone, I definitely can't use serialize.  Bonus points still out there for doing this with methods chained to instances of A/Pet.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by that? The operation involved does not make sense when chained from an instance of A/Pet.
Besides, you wouldn't want to do it through chained methods. The 
ActiveRecord overhead between statements is very inefficient. However the named scope still works on associations that return As/Pets. `@store.pets.with_current_name(name)`

Comment: You're right! I meant C/Names (as in the original outline of the problem).  So @name.pets gets me all pets with the name @name.  I wanted to chain something to that to limit the pets array to those where @name is the most recent name (to keep the approach Name centric). Thinking about this more I think it just can't be done, so your solution seems to be the way to go.  Thanks again for the help, and apologies for the confusion.

Comment: If that's what you really want there's nothing stopping you from defining a method in the C/Name model that calls the Pets named scope and supplies self as an argument.

Comment: Right. Have your solution implemented, some minor points-  `:join` should be `:joins` in your answer, and the trailing "` < pnb.created_at`", should be closed with a ")".  Thanks again, this is a generally useful pattern for me.

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't actually run the code, so typos occasionally slip through. I've fixed them now.